# Использование Lua файла в C++/cli

Tags: windows, c++-cli, lua, exe

Использую Visual Studio 2019, C/C++, исходный код Lua

Хотел бы создать .exe файл, который создает окно Windows, запускает Lua скрипт и получает из него данные. Поиск информации в интернете не дал нормальных результатов.

Вопрос. Каким образом мне можно запустить файл lua и взять из него данные ?

Код, который я уже собрал, ниже. Готов предоставить информацию о моей Visual Studio и т.д.

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <Windows.h>
extern "C" {
# include "lua.h"
# include "lauxlib.h"
# include "lualib.h"
}
using namespace Try;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application::Run(gcnew MyForm);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://rubenlaguna.com/post/2012-11-26-first-steps-in-lua-c++-integration/ прошел? пореж на кусочки и вешай на колбэки формы.

Comment: можете посмотреть как это делается сдесь: https://rubenlaguna.com/post/2012-11-26-first-steps-in-lua-c++-integration Еще я бы посоветовал книгу Иерузалемски (создателя lua) "програмирование на языке lua"